# How can I add to the order meta from input boxes?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata

I'm creating a plugin for wordpress and woocommerce. In my plugin, I've inserted an input box above the checkout form using code using 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form'. On completion of the order, I'd like to be able to add the value from that input to the order's meta data. to that end, I created this code in the functions.php file of my plugin:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'add_input_meta', 1, 2 );
function add_input_meta( $order_id, $posted ) {

    $inputsData = $_POST['InputBox'];
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'my_key', $inputsData);

}
```

The problem is, it returns NULL every time. I created the code below to see what the value of $_POST and it came up with 'array(0) { }'

```
function debugthing( $content ) {
    $content .=var_dump($_POST);
    return $content;
    die();
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'debugthing' );
```

I've exhausted every idea I could ahve about what is causing this. can anyone help?

$_POST, even php://input return an empty array or absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `woocommerce_before_checkout_form` is not the right hook to add input fields. For this hook is outside the form. This explains why you are getting null on `$_POST`
2. use any of the hook inside the `<form` in [form-checkout.php#L35](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/bd4c90dbec550aefb6dca2ce7c0903e53f2110ea/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php#L35)
3. call `woocommerce_form_field` to add fields...
4. next is you need to hook inside `process_checkout()` function.
   a. `woocommerce_after_checkout_validation` - for input validations...
   b. `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` - order created, do your meta data addition...

```
// add form fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details', 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details' );
function woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details() {
    $args =  array(
        'type'              => 'text',
        'label'             => 'My Custom field',
        'description'       => 'This is custom field',
        'placeholder'       => '',
        'required'          => true,
    );
    woocommerce_form_field( 'InputBox' , $args ); // you can call woocommerce_form_field as many as you want...
}

// validate your form field(s)
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation' );
function woocommerce_after_checkout_validation() {
    // $_POST['InputBox'] will be visible here...
    // do your validations here... forget this hook if you don't need to validate...
    // wc_add_notice( __( 'Invalid message!', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
    // call wc_add_notice if you want to invalidate the form.
}


add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed' );
function woocommerce_checkout_order_processed( $order_id ) {
    // we now have $order_id, you can now add your meta data....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your hook priority like this.

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'add_input_meta', 99, 2 );
```